# Sankey plugin vb.net winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, sankey-diagram

I just wanted to know, if anyone knows a plugin or something else for vb.net and winforms to generated sankey diagramms.

I have not tried anything, cause i have not heard about sankey since yesterday. Then i googled for sankey with vb.net and winforms, nothing found so far. So i just wanted to ask all of you, if anybody knows a plugin or something. If not im writing my own, with an excel plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try heatmap.ca, signup which gets you access to the brand new Sankey Builder (I just launched SankeyBuilder.com).  Basically you upload your data.  Then you can select fields, apply filters, enable paging (if you have many records).  Create it online for free. It generates Html Iframe code (via the share tab).  Add a WebBrowser control to your WinForms app or create in the code behind to load the Iframe.  You will then have a Sankey Diagram running in the Iframe.

Comment: thanks for your answer, using d3js and web frame now to handle this